# Videos working on my website do not work when viewed from Android browser

Tags: browser, video, media-player

My website has videos which are in MP4 format and work well when viewed from a Google Chrome browser. But when I try to load my website from the browser of an Android OS, the video doesn't show up. Is there any thing else I need to do in order to make it work? Actually the site is not done by me, so I have no details about how the site is built. I just 
wanted to know if anything special needed to be done in order to make videos work in the Android browser.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Browser's capability and Version is responsible for playing the video. There are couple of browsers which don't support the video codecs. You need to see the compatibility matrix and make sure you put correct format of the video on server.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html